# How to dissipate a lot of current

Tags: resistors, dummy-load

Lets say I want to test out a sine wave 120V 15Amp inverter by drawing 15 amps of resistive load. How can I draw this without generating very much heat, and optimized for as small as possible.

Comment: Using magic. Unfortunately that alley has recently not been very successful. Seriously: you can't make energy disappear. 120V 15A makes a decent room heater, water boiler, cargo lift, etc. You might be able to store the energy (accu? flywheel?), but all energy storage systems have a limited capacity.

Comment: 1. What they said. 2. Nichrome wire as often found in eg heater elements can be a good way of making free air high Wattage radiators. You want about R = V/I = 120/15 = 8 Ohms. This can be one resistor or coil of Nichrome or N resistors in series or parallel. A 110 VAC heater element or toaster element is close to what you want. Add wire from a second element to 'tune'. Filament lamps are very very very non linear and may give you problems with load varying.

Comment: http://www.dxzone.com/dx29468/5400-w-dummy-load.html among others.

Answer (score 3):

You are converting energy from one form to another.  So since you state that converting electrical energy into heat is not acceptable I suggest another form, say, potential energy?  drive a motor to get you to the top of a hill, a rail gun to shoot down an airplane ?  Or store it in chemical energy, and run an electrolysis bath, say, water to get you Hydrogen and Oxygen?

Comment: Ive always wanted to make an electrolysis machine. Maybe ill try to make one of those

Comment: Watch out for unintended explosions...

Comment: @skyler: Since you mentioned the word "inverter" in your question, I'd like to point out that doing any kind of _useful_ electrolysis generally requires DC. You _can_ [electrolyze water with AC](http://www.scienceforums.net/topic/23400-electrolysis-with-ac/), at least as long as the frequency is low enough, but doing that will give you mixed [oxyhydrogen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxyhydrogen) gas, which isn't good for much other than blowing up.

Comment: So for those of you who have missed the point ...  none of these suggestions were serious, it is about the transformation of energy and the lessons to be learned by considering that fact.  It's not about building rail guns to shoot at things nor is it about blowing things up.

Answer (score 2):

You **will** generate a lot of heat. 1800W actually. You can use an usual home fan heater for this task - it has similar characteristics and is suitable to work on high temperatures.

Other household heating devices - electrical stoves, water heaters may do the job as well.

Answer (score 2):

The power has to go somewhere.  Usually it is heat, and commonly such things are designed around power resistors, though in some shops I've been in they actually switched in typical electrical heaters one might use in a house, due to their cheap availability.

The only other options without generating heat are to try to push that power back into another sink - for instance convert that energy into 48V, then use an inverter to push it back onto the power line, similar to the way solar panel systems push energy onto the grid.  This produces less heat, but is far from compact and inexpensive. However it's becoming more common in equipment testing to save energy, which is only going up in cost.

Another option that is smaller and much less expensive is to convert that energy to light.  It won't be particularly small, and it will still generate a good bit of heat, but if you need more lighting in your workarea (and I've rarely seen an engineer claim there's too much light for their workarea) then this might be a good solution.

Mechanical energy might be useful - run some fans off it, or spin up a flywheel. Pump water from a storage tank to another storage tank and reverse the pump when one gets too full. Charge some batteries, or electric vehicles. An air conditioner, heat pump, or refrigerator could eat a lot of power,  though you might consider pumping heat from one place to another generating heat, but again you need to pick your poison.  If you don't want heat, then do you want light?  Electricity? Electromagnetic waves?

Comment: On converting the power to light: 1800 W of incandescent lighting would still generate a lot of heat. 1800 W of LED lighting would do a lot more than light your work area.

Comment: Yes, it is a significant amount of energy. But if you need to dissipate that much energy with as little heat as possible, light isn't a bad choice. You could even run the lightbulbs outside and let the environment soak up the light.

Comment: Any light energy which can't leave a room is going to get converted into heat, so a 1500W light is going to add 1500W to a windowless room regardless of how efficient it is.  On the other hand, if it can eliminate the need for 1,000W worth of mains-powered lighting, the net heat gain would only be 500W rather than 1,500W.

Comment: @supercat That is true in a windowless room, and in a small room over a long period there is a noticeable heating effect due to the light.  However, in large rooms with windows or skylights, where the room contains light colored surfaces, a significant amount of the light energy will dissipate outside. Even that which doesn't produces heat which is so diffuse that only engineers and air conditioning technicians would take notice.  If this is for a large scale testing farm in an environmental test chamber, a different solution is needed.  But for short test sessions it's no worse than a heater.

Answer (score 2):

Your inverter is putting out 15 A at 120 V into a resistive load.  That means (15 A)(120 V) = 1.8 kW is being moved from your inverter to somewhere.  That's basic physics you can't change.  Your only choice is what to do with the 1.8 kW.

Others have already given you plenty of ideas for how to dissipate it.  I usually use LEBs (light emitting bulbs) for this.  They are designed to dissipate significant power, are cheap, and inherently indicate when dumping power.

One issue is that they are non-linear, but this can actually be a advantage.  They look resistive (current will be proportional to voltage) in the short term of a power cycle or a few.  In the long term, this resistance varies with voltage such that lower voltages cause lower resistance.  This makes the power they dissipate less sensitive to the voltage than a resistor.  That can be useful as the inverter will still be putting out closer to the desired power than when driving a resistor when the voltage changes a bit.

However, the real point of this answer is to mention something called a ***electronic load***.  This is a device specifically designed to do what you want.  It's like a power supply in reverse.  You can adjust it to draw some set voltage, power, or current, cause load step changes, and the like.  These things are intended for testing power supplies.

High power electronic loads usually absorb the power from the power supply under test and dump it back onto the AC line.  Instead of heating the room with 1.8 kW, only a few 100 W might be released as heat, with the rest going back to the AC line.

These things are expensive and not that easy to find, so I don't recommend going out and buying one.  Now that you know what to look for, maybe you can find someone that happens to have one, or get permission to use one after hours somewhere.  Chances are a local university has one.  If you know someone that is a student or a faculty member there, maybe you can get access when nobody else is trying to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider purchasing a 1200 and a 600 watt space heater. You could get either the resistive wire/ribbon type or get a quartz rod type heater. These would make a good load for your inverter.

You have to face it that there is no such thing as trying to dissapate about 1800 watts of power without generating a lot of heat. And doing that is a very small size would be a serious challenge.

I like using resistive space heaters for loads becasue they are fully designed to throw off all the heat. They also come equipped with a very handy power cord that makes connecting the load very easy.

Answer (score 1):

Check the specs of a lady's hair dryer.  Some are 1800 watts @ 120v AC.  Connect it up/plug it in and set it on highest heat and test away.
Best after a shower :D

Failing that, try an electric frying pan.  Bacon makes a great test addition.
 :)

Answer (score 0):

15 amps of **resistive** load quite literally means the power dissipated is \$15^2\times R\$ and at 120V RMS this is going to be 1.8kW.

If, on the other hand you want to test the system with 15 amps of reactive load you'll need an impedance that is \$\dfrac{120}{15}\$ = 8 ohms and this has to be a reactive impedance such as from an inductor or capacitor.

At 60Hz, the inductor's reactance is 8 ohms therefore it's inductance is \$\dfrac{8}{2\pi F}\$ = 21.2mH.

To avoid saturation of the core (because you'll need a core) it'll be a 5" to 10" cube off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

The smallest way to dissipate that amount of power via heat is fans and load resistors attached to heatsinks. It's noisy and warms the workshop up nicely.

The other way is to water cool the loads. For less than 30V loads you can always submerge it in a bath of water and have the inflow and drain taps  cracked open. Requires metal resistors and is not a permanent solution. (I got nervous just watching it being set up, it wasn't my idea, but it got the job done)

For higher voltage you need cooling loops through heatsinks and plumbing.

Water and high voltage (over 30V) is serious stuff so not my option of choice.

Answer (score -7):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHf7Dr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This answer is incorrect.

Comment: If you build this you will release a little bit of that energy as light, a little bit as sound and quite a bit of it as heat. You will also expend some energy on a trip to your closet for a change of underwear should you decide to build this circuit.